# Python Fabric run command returns "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding"

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to connect to connect to amazon EC2 via fabric using the script below. But I'm met with a problem that I'm not sure how to solve it.

```
import os
from fabric.api import run, env, local, cd

WORK = os.getenv('HOME') + '/Work/myproject/'

env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.hosts = [
    '128.248.268.288'
]
env.key_filename = [
    '%s/aws/myproject.pem' % WORK
]

def deploy():
    print("Executing on %(host)s as %(user)s" % env)
    with cd('/sites/myproject.com/code/'):
        run('ls')
```

This is the traceback. I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 540, in main
    commands[name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mickeyckm/Work/myproject/codes/giivee/fabfile.py", line 18, in deploy
    run('ls')
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 391, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 422, in run
    channel = connections[env.host_string]._transport.open_session()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    self[real_key] = connect(user, host, port)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 140, in connect
    client.load_system_host_keys()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 151, in load_system_host_keys
    self._system_host_keys.load(filename)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 155, in load
    e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 67, in from_line
    key = RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring(key))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Any help/hint would be great appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: Does `/Users/mickeyckm/Work/myproject//aws/myproject.pem` reference a file? Is it really a PEM file? ([Does paramiko require ssh or PEM keys? rsa or dsa?](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.HostKeys-class.html)) Does the library throw a fit about the double `//` in the filename? (I sure hope not, but you never know.)

Comment: I have fixed the //, it will haveing the same issue. any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw some places where Incorrect Padding error was resulted from binascii module and it was mostly when the string you pass has some extraneous white-space characters.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.a2b_base64('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

In your case, it the various properties you set for your `env` object. Do something like this for your key file location and see if that works.

```
filelocation = os.path.join(WORK,'aws/myproject.pem')
env.key_filename = [filelocation]
```

Comment: hi senthil, i've followed ur advice, i tried running binascii.a2b_base64() on the filelocation. It wasn't working at first. So I fixed it. However, I still receive the same error when it comes to run() command.

Comment: hi senthil, i realised one thing, filelocation = os.path.join(WORK,'aws') will work, but when i tried to do this filelocation = os.path.join(WORK,'aws/myproject.pem'), the binascii, it will return error. somehow the .pem makes a difference

Comment: @Mickey, try sending filelocation.strip() explicitly and see if you still get the problem?

Comment: tried that, it didn't work as well. I even went to the extend of renaming it to 'mickeyckm' instead of 'mickeyckm.pem'. It passed the binascii.a2b_base64(filelocation) but it fails when i run the the run command.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in fact, i realised the known_hosts file was corrupted. I deleted the corrupted entry, and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. It may contain lines with duplicate entries or be corrupted in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tracked it down to some corruption in my .ssh/known_hosts file.

I thus added to my .bashrc

```
alias deploy='mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.tmp; fab <myfabscript>; mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts.old ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

(obviously putting the right fabric script where `<myfabscript>` is) and now all works fine when I simply run "deploy"!