# Connecting to EC2 using keypair (.pem file) via Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

Anyone has any Fabric recipe that shows how to connect to EC2 using the pem file?

I tried writing it with this manner:
[Python Fabric run command returns "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063796/python-fabric-run-command-returns-binascii-error-incorrect-padding)

But I'm faced with some encoding issue, when I execute the `run()` function.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To use the pem file I generally add the pem to the ssh agent, then simply refer to the username and host:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/ec2key.pem
fab -H ubuntu@ec2-host deploy
```

or specify the env information (without the key) like the example you linked to:

```
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.hosts = [
    'ec2-host'
]
```

and run as normal:

```
fab deploy
```

Answer (score 35):

Without addressing your encoding issue, you might put your EC2 stuff into an ssh config file:

- ~/.ssh/config

or, if global:

- /etc/ssh_config

There you can specify your host, ip address, user, identify file, etc., so it's a simple matter of:

```
ssh myhost
```

Example:

```
Host myhost
  User ubuntu
  HostName 174.129.254.215
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

For more details: `man ssh_config`

Answer (score 11):

Another thing you can do is set the key_filename in the env variable:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5327496/1729558

Comment: This is the right answer imo.  To be more explicit: `env.key_filename = '/path/to/keyfile.pem'`.