# Using an SSH keyfile with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

How do you configure fabric to connect to remote hosts using SSH keyfiles (for example, Amazon EC2 instances)?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Also worth mentioning here that you can use the command line args for this:

```
fab command -i /path/to/key.pem [-H [user@]host[:port]]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, adding the SSH key to my keychain did however, by running ` eval 'ssh-agent' ` (<- use backticks here, not quotes) first and then `ssh-add /path/to/key.pem`. After that I could run fab without the -i flag.

Answer (score 154):

Finding a simple fabfile with a working example of SSH keyfile usage isn't easy for some reason. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.y3xz.com/post/3898560556/fabric-ssh-with-keyfile) about it ([with a matching gist](https://gist.github.com/872506)).

Basically, the usage goes something like this:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['host.name.com']
env.user = 'user'
env.key_filename = '/path/to/keyfile.pem'

def local_uname():
    local('uname -a')

def remote_uname():
    run('uname -a')
```

The important part is setting the `env.key_filename` environment variable, so that the Paramiko configuration can look for it when connecting.

Comment: in the practice this is the better answer.

Comment: `env.key_filename` [can contain a list of strings](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#key-filename) to try multiple keyfiles for a connection.

Comment: I was setting the key programmatically in one of my tasks using the `settings` context manager and couldn't get it to recognize the key_filename until I changed `key_filename='/path/to/key'` to `key_filename=['/path/to/key']` so if anyone else is having trouble, making key_filename a list of keys might fix it. This is with fab 1.10.1 and Paramiko 1.15.2

Comment: fabric.api doesnt exist

Comment: @AseemHegshetye, It was removed in the latest Fabric 2. This answer is for Fabric 1.

Comment: I'd prefer explicit imports instead of import *

Comment: can someone mention the explicit imports in this scenario?

Comment: Despite defining the env.hosts = ['host-name.fqdn-format']. Following input is asked: No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Answer (score 67):

Another cool feature available as of Fabric 1.4 - [Fabric now supports SSH configs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#ssh-config).

If you already have all the SSH connection parameters in your `~/.ssh/config` file, Fabric will natively support it, all you need to do is add:

```
env.use_ssh_config = True
```

at the beginning of your fabfile.

Comment: Very useful!  If you run into errors like `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' /path/to/.ssh/key'` or `Login password for ' root':` just make sure you have no whitespaces in your `.ssh/config`. It's for example `User=root` instead of `User = root`...

Comment: @dennis This still seems to be an issue in 2016..! Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

For **fabric2** in fabfile use the following:

```
from fabric import task, Connection

@task
def staging(ctx):
    ctx.name = 'staging'
    ctx.user = 'ubuntu'
    ctx.host = '192.1.1.1'
    ctx.connect_kwargs.key_filename = os.environ['ENV_VAR_POINTS_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH']

@task
def do_something_remote(ctx):
    with Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs) as conn:
        conn.sudo('supervisorctl status')
```

and run it with:

```
fab staging do_something_remote
```

**UPDATE:**
For multiple hosts (one host will do also) you can use this:

```
from fabric2 import task, SerialGroup

@task
def staging(ctx):
    conns = SerialGroup(
        'user@10.0.0.1',
        'user@10.0.0.2',
        connect_kwargs=
        {
            'key_filename': os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY_TO_HOST']
        })
    ctx.CONNS = conns
    ctx.APP_SERVICE_NAME = 'google'

@task
def stop(ctx):
    for conn in ctx.CONNS:
        conn.sudo('supervisorctl stop ' + ctx.APP_SERVICE_NAME)
```

and run it with fab or fab2:

```
fab staging stop
```

Comment: This is the right way to do in fabric 2.x , Since all the other answers won't work.

Comment: How to support multiple hosts in this `staging` task ?

Comment: @Black_Rider, added it to my answer

Answer (score 15):

For me, the following didn't work:

```
env.user=["ubuntu"]
env.key_filename=['keyfile.pem']
env.hosts=["xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
```

or

```
fab command -i /path/to/key.pem [-H [user@]host[:port]]
```

However, the following did:

```
env.key_filename=['keyfile.pem']
env.hosts=["ubuntu@xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
```

or

```
env.key_filename=['keyfileq.pem']
env.host_string="ubuntu@xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Your first example works for me if you use `env.user="ubuntu"` instead of `env.user=["ubuntu"]`.

Answer (score 7):

I had to do this today, my .py file was as simple as possible, like the one posted in the answer of @YuvalAdam but still I kept getting prompted for a password...

Looking at the `paramiko` (the library used by fabric for ssh) log, I found the line:

> Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

I updated `paramiko` with:

```
sudo pip install paramiko --upgrade
```

And now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me on py3.7, fabric2.5.0 and paramiko 2.7.1.

However, using the PKey attribute in the documentation does work: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/concepts/authentication.html#private-key-objects

```
from paramiko import RSAKey
ctx.connect_kwargs.pkey = RSAKey.from_private_key_file('path_to_your_aws_key')
with Connection(ctx.host, user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs) as conn:
    //etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, Fabric will support .ssh/config file settings after a fashion, but using a pem file for ec2 seems to be problematic.   IOW a properly setup .ssh/config file will work from the command line via 'ssh servername' and fail to work with 'fab sometask' when env.host=['servername'].

This was overcome by specifying the env.key_filename='keyfile' in my fabfile.py and duplicating the IdentityFile entry already in my .ssh/config.

This could be either Fabric or paramiko, which in my case was Fabric 1.5.3 and Paramiko 1.9.0.