# How to establish a SSH connection via proxy using Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to establish a SSH connection between a Windows PC and a Linux server(amazon ec2).

I decided to use Fabric API implemented using python.

I have Putty installed on the Windows PC.

My fabfile script looks like this:

```
import sys
from fabric.api import *


def testlive():
  print 'Test live ...'
  run("uptime")

env.use_ssh_config = False
env.host_string = "host.something.com"
env.user = "myuser"
env.keys_filename = "./private_openssh.key"
env.port = 22
env.gateway = "proxyhost:port"

testlive()
```

I am running Fabric in the same directory with the private key.

I am able to login on this machine using Putty.

**The problem:** I am constantly asked for Login password for specified user.

Based on other posts([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697907/fabric-does-not-use-ssh-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327465/using-an-ssh-keyfile-with-fabric)) I already tried:

- pass as a list the key file to env.keys_filename
- use username@host_string
- use env.host instead of env.host_string

How to properly configure Fabric to deal with proxy server and ssh private key file ?

Comment: `"host.something.com"` equal to `user@ip_addr_numbers` ? Your module how to  handle `wellcome` and `handshake` ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work.

```
env.key_filename = "./private_openssh.key"
```

(notice the typo in your attempt)

Answer (score 2):

Fabric's API is best avoided really, way too many bugs and issues (see issue tracker).

You can do what you want in Python with the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.utils import load_private_key

client = ParallelSSHClient(['host.something.com'],
                           pkey=load_private_key('private_openssh.key'),
                           proxy_host='proxyhost',
                           proxy_port=<proxy port number>,
                           user='myuser',
                           proxy_user='myuser')
output = client.run_command('uname')
for line in output['host.something.com'].stdout:
    print(line)
```

ParallelSSH is available from pip as `parallel-ssh`.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. I will try it asap.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTYgen is what you will use to generate your SSH key then upload the copied SSH key to your Cloud Management portal - [See Joyant](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows)

Comment: That is by default mandatory :) I already did that long time ago :)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to generate and authenticate a private key, to do so, you need PuTTYgen to generate the SSH access using RSA key with password, key comment and conform the key passphrase, here is a step by step guide documentation [SSH Access using RSA Key Authentication](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/qn_010_configuring_ssh_with_rsa_authentication.pdf)