# Python Fabric roledefs and ssh keys

Tags: fabric

As discussed in [Using an SSH keyfile with Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327465/using-an-ssh-keyfile-with-fabric), it is possible to set an ssh keyfile using `env.key_filename`.  How does this setting interact with defining remote hosts in `env.roledefs`?

If I set key_filename, will Fabric try to use that key with all hosts?  What if different hosts require different keys?

A workaround would be to set `env.hosts` and `env.key_filename` in a separate task for each set of hosts, but is there a way that makes use of the roledefs feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `env.key_filename` to a list of filenames, each of which would then be tried for each connection. Anything more specific you would have to script yourself.

From [this doc](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/env.html#key-filename).

So to answer:

> .. but is there a way that makes use of the roledefs feature?

No.