# How to user fabric on localhost without password?

Tags: fabric, provisioning, salt-stack

I would like to use fabric to deploy a bunch of libraries on to a box that it being automatically provisioned with salt-stack. Currently the function is run as

```
fab deploy_libs:args,kwards -Hlocalhost
```

How can I run this command without requiring a password, which obviously won't be a thing I can do as it's automated?

Disclaimer: There may be a significantly better way of doing this and I'm not precious about it.

Comment: Does this help, maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327465/using-an-ssh-keyfile-with-fabric

Answer (score 1):

To run a command on the local machine from inside `fabfile.py`, you can use [`fabric.operations.local`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html).

Since you're using salt, you might also consider doing the extra work to use the [`cmd.run`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) state, which, once you've set up the correct dependencies, lets you take advantage of salt's dependency graph and run some operations in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, this is the thing to do. Bypass fabric if you've got salt altogether.