# Paramiko parse raise Exception when Using SSH keyfile with Fabric

Tags: python, ssh

I'm newbie using `ssh_key` in fabric. After I follow the instruction in [Using an SSH keyfile with Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327465/using-an-ssh-keyfile-with-fabric/47666600#47666600), in my code:

```
import os

from fabric.api import *  

env.hosts = ['host.name.com']
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = '/root/.ssh/config'

def local_uname():
local('uname -a')
```

In file config, there is my `id_rsa.pub` key. I get an error like this:

```
File "paramiko/paramiko/config.py", line 68, in parse raise Exception("Unparsable line {}".format(line)) 
Exception: Unparsable line
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set a config file like

```
env.ssh_config_path = '/root/.ssh/config'
```

or an SSH key like

```
env.key_filename = '/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

But setting a config file to be used as your SSH key makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got it. It work to my case, but I still have an error that Fabric asks for root password.

Comment: Well then create a new question with the log output you are seeing.

Comment: No need, because it can solve with another explain related fabric. Thanks Nils

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark this answer as correct, too.